Why isn't WORKING_DIRECTORY being used in my cmake tests?
I'm trying to set the working directory for a CMake test, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's the really simple test I'm trying to use:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(working_directory_error LANGUAGES CXX)
enable_testing()

add_executable(main main.cpp)

add_test(main_test main WORKING_DIRECTORY "C:/")

main.cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path workingDirectory = std::filesystem::current_path();
    bool workingDirectoryIsC = workingDirectory == std::filesystem::path("C:/");
    std::cout << "Working directory is " << workingDirectory << " which is "
    << (workingDirectoryIsC ? "right" : "wrong") << std::endl;
    return workingDirectoryIsC ? 0 : 1;
}

console
C:\dev\repros\working_directory_error>cmake -B out -G Ninja
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32825.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (1.3s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/repros/working_directory_error/out

C:\dev\repros\working_directory_error>cmake --build out
[2/2] Linking CXX executable main.exe

C:\dev\repros\working_directory_error>ctest --test-dir out --output-on-failure
Internal ctest changing into directory: C:/dev/repros/working_directory_error/out
Test project C:/dev/repros/working_directory_error/out
    Start 1: main_test
1/1 Test #1: main_test ........................***Failed    0.03 sec
Working directory is "C:\\dev\\repros\\working_directory_error\\out" which is wrong


0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.03 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - main_test (Failed)
Errors while running CTest

I've tried both MSVC and Ninja generators on Windows, and Ninja on Linux using WSL. I've tried running from the out folder in case --test-dir was somehow overriding the working directory. Nothing seems to work.
Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Not really an answer to your question but if you want to have the working directory set to some value in order to load test data then an easier approach might be to use target_compile_definitions to create a define which hard codes they path into your executable, that way it doesn't matter how your executable is run, it'll always be able to find the data

@AlanBirtles I really appreciate this comment, because even though you're right it's not answering the question directly, it is getting at the heart of what I'm trying to do: have a consistent data folder, and your solution helps have a simple setup for all tests.
Ultimately, I'm trying to do something different, which is use one data location if the tests are run through cmake, and a different location if the test are moved and run manually. If you have a general target-based solution that can do this (instead of the test-based solution I'm currently using), I'd love to hear it!

Try the following:
add_test(NAME main_test COMMAND main WORKING_DIRECTORY "C:/")

I believe the issue is that you are using the older, less flexible form of add_test.
Unlike the above NAME signature, target names are not supported in the command-line.

That completely solved the problem, thanks! It would have been nice if the initial cmake command issued a warning or something, since WORKING_DIRECTORY seems to be ignored with the old add_test.
